# Using neural networks in VIdeo summarization?

Tags: java, neural-network, video-processing

I have made a program in Java that summarizes videos. This file will read audio and video files, break them into number of shots, depending on heuristic they would be assigned some weight. And based on the percentage value provided by the user, only shots with higher weight are taken as a part of summary.

Is there a possibility that the thresholds that are: Pixel motion, Key Frame Threshold and the percentage, as mentioned above, to be calculated as per the type of video .... using some training preferably by neural networks ?

Comment: Are you asking if it's possible? Then my guess is "yes".

Comment: I've done quite a bit of work on neural networks, but I'm not sure what you're asking here. If you give a clear example of what you're talking about I may be able to help you :)

Comment: @J.Ashworth When I have to run this program, I load a video (avi) file and wait for the summarization of the video. But for different videos sometimes I have to set different thresholds e.g. for Pixel motion, entropy, key frame threshold etc. I want the program to set the thresholds itself after checking the video..... I hope am clear

Comment: How do **you** determine the threshold value(s)?